# How to remove groups of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some trouble with a query that i don't know how to proceed with

Table structure

```
create table event(
  evn_id int identity(1,1),
  name varchar(90)
)

create table eventdate(
  evd_id int identity(1,1),
  evd_evn_id int references event(evn_id),
  evd_start smalldatetime,
  evd_end smalldatetime null,
  evd_picked bit,
)
```

Testdata

```
Insert into eventdate
VALUES('1','1','2018-08-28 09:00:00','NULL','1'),
    ('1','2','2018-04-26 09:00:00','NULL','0'),
    ('1','3','2018-02-25 09:00:00','NULL','0'), 
    ('2','4','2018-03-26 15:00:00','NULL','1'),
    ('2','5','2018-04-25 09:00:00','NULL','0')

Insert into event
VALUES('1','test'),
('2','test')
```

Every event can have 1 or more eventdate and a eventdate has 1 event

I have the following that gives me a list of eventdates with 1 or 0 picked dates

```
SELECT * 
FROM eventdate
WHERE evd_evn_id IN(
    SELECT evd_evn_id
    FROM eventdate
    GROUP BY evd_evn_id
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN evd_picked = 1 then 1 else null end) <= 1)
ORDER BY evd_evn_id
```

What i now want to do is remove all records for each evd_evn_id if the evd_evn_id 
has a date that is a picked date(evd_picked = 1) that is created before 
 for example "20180613"

What it should return is

```
'2','4','2018-03-26 15:00:00','NULL','1'
'2','5','2018-04-25 09:00:00','NULL','0'
```

Comment: Your query does not refer to the two tables you have specified.  That makes it really hard to understand your actual question.  Sample data and desired results really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Output Clause with DELETE](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/output-clause-sample-code-with-insert-update-delete-sql-server-2005.aspx) command in this requirement
There is exactly a similar sample in referenced document.

Here is the SQL script I can suggest for you

```
declare @EventID table
(
  evn_id int
)

DELETE FROM eventdate
OUTPUT DELETED.evd_evn_id
INTO @EventID(evn_id)
WHERE evd_picked  = 1 and
      evd_start < '20180613'


DELETE FROM event
where evn_id in (select evn_id from @EventID)
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question, you want all the records from your eventdate table for an event if any of the event dates have been picked AND the start date is before '20180613'.

I am assuming this from the results you expected.  I would use the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM eventdate
WHERE evd_id in(
select evd_id from eventdate    WHERE evd_start < '2018-06-13' and evd_picked = 1)
```

TO DELETE:

```
DELETE FROM  eventdate
WHERE evd_id in(
select evd_id from eventdate    WHERE evd_start < '2018-06-13' and evd_picked = 1)
```